# Is cubin the most efficient deployment format?

Tags: cuda

Given I know the OS version and the capability of my device, in advance, of my deployment server. Is cubin the most efficient file to deploy?

Comment: You are going to have to define what you mean by efficient.

Comment: Time is what I mean. So, if I am compiling against a specific version for a server that is under my control, then what is the compilation format that will give me the least execution time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that should significantly affect execution time from the perspective of how the code was compiled with respect to device options, is [JIT compiling](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#compilation-workflow).

Assuming the JIT cache is large enough to hold the device-specific compiled version, the impact of this should only be felt the first time the app is run.  Thereafter the JIT cache will contain the correct code.

If you want to avoid this first-time-run penalty, the only thing necessary should be to pass `nvcc` [appropriate switches](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation) to target your device during compilation of the app.

A cubin file [only contains device binary code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#command-option-description).  A *fatbin* may contain device binary code for multiple devices.  By having the correct device binary code available, you can [avoid JIT start-up delay](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#fatbinaries).  Ultimately, these formats (cubin or fatbin) will be collected into the executable containing both host and device code.  You do not need to explicitly target cubin or fatbin, which would generate files containing device code only.